# Change color of bootstrap form input textarea?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I'd like to change the font color of a bootstrap form that the user types. So, when the form is loaded the placeholder text is grey. When the user starts typing I'd like that font to change color.

This is easy to do with all 'regular' fields using this css declaration:

```
input[type="text"] {
color: #63AEEB
}
```

BUT - I want it for a < textarea > and I thought this would work but no love:

```
input[type="textarea"] {
color: #63AEEB
}
```

This is my current code here:

```
<textarea style= "background-color: #494949" cols="24" class="form-control" id="inf_custom_ConferenceDescription" name="inf_custom_ConferenceDescription" rows="5" placeholder="PLACE HOLDER HERE'" /></textarea>
```

Could it be an issue that I am applying a background-color on the textarea?

Thanks!

Comment: You should change your second style rule so the selector is `textarea`

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is not right.

Change this

```
input[type="textarea"] {
    color: #63AEEB
}
```

to

```
textarea.form-control {
    color: #63AEEB
}
```